# Unable to load static file in Spring4

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a sample Spring MVC project but  static file are not getting loaded.I am getting below mentioned error.

http://localhost:8080/BPMEI/static/css/bootstrap.css Failed to load resource: **the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I will be grateful if someone can help me out to fix this issue.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kciZr.png)

### Configuration Code

```
 package com.dgsl.bpm.configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dgsl.bpm")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

}
```

### **Initializer code**

```
package com.dgsl.bpm.configuration;

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    }

}
```

### JSP Code

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Student Enrollment Form</title>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Where is your jsp file reside? in `WEB-INF` or `WEB-INF/{some_other_folder}` ?

Comment: JSP file is at  'WEB-INF\views\welcome.jsp'

Comment: Could you try `<c:url value='../../static/css/bootstrap.css' />`

Comment: I made the changes but still not working but error got changed as mentioned below                                                                               'localhost/:10 GET http://localhost:8080/static/css/bootstrap.css '

Comment: Follow my answer dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change addResourceHandlers like

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

and also change css file name 'bootstrap.min.css'

Answer (score 1):

may be you made a wrong mapping.

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
```

this code should works, i tested it on my local machine.
addResourceLocations("/static/") the last slash is **mandatory**
in sping-core-4.2.5-release.jar StringUtils.java  has the following code

```
public static String applyRelativePath(String path, String relativePath) {
        int separatorIndex = path.lastIndexOf(FOLDER_SEPARATOR);
        if (separatorIndex != -1) {
            String newPath = path.substring(0, separatorIndex);
            if (!relativePath.startsWith(FOLDER_SEPARATOR)) {
                newPath += FOLDER_SEPARATOR;
            }
            return newPath + relativePath;
        }
        else {
            return relativePath;
        }
}
```

if not end with a slash, this method will return **relativePath**

FYI, when i view your attached picture, i found "bootstrap.min.css" in your project. don't forget to use right file name. i wish my suggestion can help you

Comment: changed the code -'registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");'  still not working

Answer (score 1):

To F2:if you let it download itself instead of me downloading css files and telling Spring where they are,you must let the js files or somethings publish to the web which is not controlled by yourself.The building-owner’s purpose is how to load the static file in a Spring MVC project.I think the problem is on the code of `addResourceLocations`,it should be `addResourceLocations ("classpath:/static/");`

Comment: oh,i am sorry,is not to F2,is to F1

Answer (score 0):

Change your addResourceHandlers definition like below and try:-

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the context path in your url:

```
<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/bootstrap.css' />
```

This will give you the url value:

```
BPMEI/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

Let me know if that works.